# Diluting a $0.5M$ solution to $0.1M$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, chemistry

> Using the $0.5 M$ solution how will you prepare a solution of $0.1 M$? Glassware provided is $3$ volumetric flasks of size $500, 250$ and $100 ml$. All bulb pipettes are provided and the sizes are $10, 20, 25$ and $50ml$.

I'm thinking of the formula $C_1V_1 = C_2V_2$ and I have a little confuse of how to select my $V_1$(volume 1) and $V_2$(volume 2).

Answer (score 1):

You need to mix one unit of concentrated (.5M) solution with four units of solvent.

You want to start with $c_1V_1 = c_2V_2$.

Let's say, you want to make 500 ml of 0.1M solution, than your $V_2$ is 500 ml and $V_1 = V_2\frac{c_2}{c_1}$: $V_1$ is now 100 ml. You have to pour 100 ml of concentrated solution into 500 ml flask and fill it to 500 with solvent.